# Extracting specific dates from strings

Tags: python, string, date

I'm attempting to extract some specific dates from text. The text looks like the following:

```
'Shares of Luxury Goods Makers Slip on Russia Export Ban',
'By Investing.com\xa0-\xa0Mar 15, 2022 By Dhirendra Tripathi',
'Investing.com – Stocks of European retailers such as LVMH (PA:LVMH), Kering (PA:PRTP), H&M (ST:HMb), Moncler (MI:MONC) and Hermès (PA:HRMS) were all down around 4% Tuesday... ',
'',
'',
'',
' ',
'Europe Stocks Open Lower as Wider Sanctions, Covid Rebound Hit Mood',
'By Investing.com\xa0-\xa0Mar 15, 2022 By Geoffrey Smith\xa0',
'Investing.com -- European stock markets opened lower on Tuesday as a fresh round of EU sanctions, a rebound in Covid-19 cases and more signs of red-hot inflation all weighed on... ',
'',
'\xa0',
```

Obviously in this small snippet id like to extract only: March 15 2022 and March 15 2022.

I've attempted:

```
datefinder.find_dates(text)

dateutil.parser
```

The first returns all the dates I want plus a load of others that don't exist.

The second returns "String does not contain a date:"

Can anyone think of the best way I can do this?

Comment: Just to clarify, do you want your program to return `Mar 15, 2022`?

Comment: Is the date always in the form of `month` `day` `year`?

Comment: Hello @Justin , in datetime format would be better however, that could be done later if necessary.

Comment: @FreddyMcloughlan yes that's correct, always in that sequence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regular expression

```
import re

line = r'By Investing.com\xa0-\xa0Mar 15, 2022 By Geoffrey Smith\xa0'

re_results = re.findall(r'[A-Z][a-z]{2} \d{1,2}, \d{4}', line)

for result in re_results:
    print(result)
```

Output:

```
Mar 15, 2022
```

You can test regular expressions here https://regexr.com/

Comment: Excellent such a simple solution, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Using `re`:

```
import re

x = ['Shares of Luxury Goods Makers Slip on Russia Export Ban',
     'By Investing.com\xa0-\xa0Mar 15, 2022 By Dhirendra Tripathi',
     'Investing.com – Stocks of European retailers such as LVMH (PA:LVMH), Kering (PA:PRTP), H&M (ST:HMb), Moncler (MI:MONC) and Hermès (PA:HRMS) were all down around 4% Tuesday... ',
     '',
     '',
     '',
     ' ',
     'Europe Stocks Open Lower as Wider Sanctions, Covid Rebound Hit Mood',
     'By Investing.com\xa0-\xa0Mar 15, 2022 By Geoffrey Smith\xa0',
     'Investing.com -- European stock markets opened lower on Tuesday as a fresh round of EU sanctions, a rebound in Covid-19 cases and more signs of red-hot inflation all weighed on... ',
     '',
     '\xa0', ]

for line in x:
    m = re.search(r'\w{3} \d{1,2}, \d{4}', line)
    if m:
        print(m.group())
```

Outputs:

```
Mar 15, 2022
Mar 15, 2022
```

Note that this will only match dates in a form of `[3 letters] [1-2 numbers] [4 numbers]`